# Is cache line management possible in JS on V8

Tags: javascript, memory-management, v8

I know how important cache lines can be for performance when writing in bare-metal languages like c or cpp. I'm curious if attempting to manage cache lines in JavaScript is possible or if the VM's memory allocator does too much magic for that to work, or if it attempts to allocate in cache line size blocks where it can.

If it is possible, what would that look like?

Comment: Trying to work around pretty much any VMs cache line management would in all likelihood be counter-productive as the VM itself is managing both low- and high-level memory allocations.